# Removing value after second instance of -

Tags: excel

I have a list of item numbers which have a size separated with `-`. Normally there is only one hyphen separating the item and its size like this:

```
     Item ID
    VTG1001-5
    VTG1001-6
    VTG1001-8
    VTG1002-5
    VTG1002-6
    ...
```

But in some cases there is the item number, its collection and then size like this:

```
     Item ID
  VTG1001-730-5
  VTG1001-730-6
  VTG1001-730-8
  VTG1002-730-5
  VTG1002-730-6
    ...
```

And I can't use a built in feature like *text to columns* because then it would remove the collection if I chose to split based on the `-`.

How can I separate this column based on the second instance of `-`? The ideal result would be:

```
     Item ID
   VTG1001-730
   VTG1001-730
   VTG1001-730
   VTG1002-730
   VTG1002-730
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with.

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("-",A1,FIND("-",A1)+1)),A1,LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1,FIND("-",A1)+1)-1))
```

You're feeding the start position to the 2nd find based on the position of the first hyphen.

Comment: It does that. If you put put all the sample data you gave into a column it should give you the output you want.

Answer (score 0):

You were right to use text to column.  You can use text to columns to separate it in to 3 columns.  Then in another sheet, join the first 2 column with a formula:

```
=A2&"-"&B2
```

Then in the 2nd column of that new sheet, you can just do a simple:

```
=IF(C2="","",C2)
```

This will bring the in the third column from the separated data if there is a value or just leave it blank.

That should give you the the format you want.

You probable want to copy and paste with values after you are done if you just want the flat data.

Heres what it looks like on my spread sheet

[image]